# A branch named 'deploy' already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

In a [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) deploy of a Ruby-on-Rails project the deployment fails and aborts with a fatal error. The message is

```
A branch named 'deploy' already exists.
```

Of course the branch already exists, because we are trying to deploy that branch. Any idea what goes wrong? This is the log, we are using Git, the capistrano branch is set to `deploy`, the capistrano version is `2.15.9`, ruby version is `2.3.1`

```
$ cap staging deploy    
    triggering load callbacks
  * 2016-09-13 12:12:38 executing `staging'
    triggering start callbacks for `deploy'
  * 2016-09-13 12:12:38 executing `multistage:ensure'
  * 2016-09-13 12:12:38 executing `deploy'
  * 2016-09-13 12:12:38 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2016-09-13 12:12:38 executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@git.my-company.com:developer-group/my-site.git deploy"
    command finished in 615ms
  * executing "git clone -q -b deploy --depth 1 git@git.my-company.com:developer-group/my-site.git /home/my-user/sites/my-domain.de/releases/20160913101239 && cd /home/my-user/sites/my-domain.de/releases/20160913101239 && git checkout -q -b deploy fe7bd80727d9cce1a275a531c6e21b84e15ab0cd && rm -Rf /home/my-user/sites/my-domain.de/releases/20160913101239/.git && (echo fe7bd80727d9cce1a275a531c6e21b84e15ab0cd > /home/my-user/sites/my-domain.de/releases/20160913101239/REVISION)"
    servers: ["my-server"]
    [my-server] executing command
 ** [my-server :: err] fatal: A branch named 'deploy' already exists.
    command finished in 2481ms
```

The command that fails is `git checkout -q -b deploy sha_value`.

Comment: Well, it seems your code is not working. For any additional clues, you need to provide significantly more information.

Comment: It sounds like you have some configuration error in your Capistrano configuration.

I am assuming you are using something like git for version control.

What Capistrano tries to do when deploying is to ssh into the server and then check out whatever branch you told it to deploy.

If you configured it to create the branch `deploy` and track an upstream branch (e.g. origin/deploy) when running the deploy script, then it will not be able to do that if the branch already exists.

Did you modify the `update_code` part of your capistrano config in any way? That might be why this is happening

Comment: Sorry I added more information

Answer (score 2):

It turns out **deploy** is a reserved name for Capistrano, so you are not allowed to use it as a branch name. Capistrano apparently tries to create a temporary "deploy" branch if you deploy a Git project.
https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/359

In general "deploy", "doctor", and "install" are all reserved names in Capistrano, which are also not allowed as stage names (such as "production" or "staging").

Comment: To clarify: the `deploy` branch name is reserved in Capistrano v2. In Capistrano v3 there is no limitation on branch names.